# z-index fail with overflow

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with the following html and css trying to get the z-index to keep my secondary-panel on top of the scroll but still static with its content.

> JSFiddle - without scroll bar: https://jsfiddle.net/kyp0gd2r/1/

> JSFiddle - with scroll bar: https://jsfiddle.net/kyp0gd2r/2/

**HTML & CSS:**

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.single-pump-view-container-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid purple;
    height: calc(100% - 3px);
}

.inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
    height: calc(100% - 2em - 3px);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.single-pump-controller {
  width: 290px;
  background: yellow;
}

.data-channel-panel-area {
  margin: 1em 10px 0 10px;
  width: 570px;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 534px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.secondary-panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 120px);
  top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 999;
}

.right-area {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div  style="padding: 0px 5px;height: calc(100% - 135px);">
    <div class="single-pump-view-container-wrapper">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
          <div class="single-pump-controller">left</div>
          <div class="data-channel-panel-area">
            <div class="container-wrapper">
                <p>Title Goes Here</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
                <div class="secondary-panel">ssss</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-wrapper">
                <p>Title Goes Here</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
                <div class="secondary-panel">ssss</div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-area"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Stack-blitz version: (Did this one to test that it was not angular causing my issue, also closest to actual code)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wezlub?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Answer (score 0):

In `.data-channel-panel-area`, `overflow-y: auto;` cannot be used in combination with e.g. `overflow-x: visible;`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Description):

> Setting one axis to `visible` (the default) while setting the other to a *different* value results in `visible` behaving as `auto`

`auto` will scroll on overflow. One alternative would be to set both axes to `visible`, then implement your own scrollbar for `.data-channel-panel-area`, though it may not be worth going that far. Another approach might be to move `.secondary-panel` elements out of `.data-channel-panel-area`, then position them with a JavaScript scroll event.

In any case, consider that it might be bad UX to have an element appearing over a scrollbar and under probably wouldn't look good.

Comment: under definitely won't be good,  but over would be ok, it's a popup not permanently visible.  I will check out the mdn, thankyou.

unfortunatly overflow of any kind breaks the z-index and I don't know how to push it up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```js
var secondary_panel = document.getElementsByClassName('secondary-panel');

document.getElementsByClassName('data-channel-panel-area')[0].addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrolled = this.scrollTop;

  if (scrolled >= 18 && scrolled <= 231) {
    secondary_panel[0].style.position = "fixed";
    secondary_panel[0].style.top = scrolled * 0.0001 + 'px';
    secondary_panel[0].style.marginTop = "25px";
    secondary_panel[0].style.marginLeft = "-240px";
  } else {
    secondary_panel[0].style.position = "absolute";
    secondary_panel[0].style.top = '15px';
    secondary_panel[0].style.marginTop = "0px";
    secondary_panel[0].style.marginLeft = "0px";

  }

  if (scrolled >= 286 && scrolled <= 490) {
    secondary_panel[1].style.position = "fixed";
    secondary_panel[1].style.top = scrolled * 0.0001 + 'px';
    secondary_panel[1].style.marginTop = "25px";
    secondary_panel[1].style.marginLeft = "-240px";
  } else {
    secondary_panel[1].style.position = "absolute";
    secondary_panel[1].style.top = '15px';
    secondary_panel[1].style.marginTop = "0px";
    secondary_panel[1].style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.single-pump-view-container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  height: calc(100% - 3px);
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  height: calc(100% - 2em - 3px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.single-pump-controller {
  width: 290px;
  background: yellow;
}

.data-channel-panel-area {
  margin: 1em 10px 0 10px;
  width: 570px;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 534px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.secondary-panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 120px);
  top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 999;
}

.right-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="padding: 0px 5px;height: calc(100% - 135px);">
    <div class="single-pump-view-container-wrapper">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="single-pump-controller">left</div>
        <div class="data-channel-panel-area">
          <div class="container-wrapper">
            <p>Title Goes Here</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur
              a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt
              mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a
              odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
            <div class="secondary-panel">ssss</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-wrapper">
            <p>Title Goes Here</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur
              a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt
              mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a
              odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
            <div class="secondary-panel">ssss</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet nisi eget metus vestibulum gravida. Praesent pulvinar hendrerit est, et eleifend sem vulputate id. Suspendisse ex purus, vestibulum ut enim ut, euismod finibus ex. Curabitur
              a sapien in est malesuada sollicitudin. Donec aliquam odio nec lacinia interdum. Morbi luctus imperdiet libero, id placerat velit consectetur vitae. Nulla congue ut mi id tincidunt. Vestibulum dolor ipsum, auctor tristique nisl sed, tincidunt
              mollis risus. Suspendisse sollicitudin, nisl vel semper gravida, neque lectus laoreet erat, quis fermentum dui tortor a nibh. Donec sed massa volutpat, pharetra lacus eget, tempus mauris. Nam sed posuere ipsum, a porta leo. Vestibulum a
              odio ut quam tristique mollis. Morbi tristique faucibus elementum. Morbi nibh est, dapibus ut libero nec, mattis cursus ligula.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-area"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Very good attempt and very appreciative, but the outcome i am looking for is the red bar to be the highest z-index and outside the scroll. see without scrollbar for the desired result, but with a scroll.

Comment: @Crash1hd just remove transform property in data-channel-panel-area class

Comment: That puts it on top but when you scroll it goes the opposite direction and its off to the far right

Comment: @Crash1hd also change  secondary_panel.style.top = scrolled + 'px'; to scrolled*0.00001 + 'px'; for both the indexes

Comment: That leaves it in the top right corner, but it does not disappear when scrolled off the screen nor is it in its spot on the blue area. :) i am surprised there is no way to do this with just css though.  basically, the overflow resets the z-index and I can't seem to figure out a way to change that.  (Remove the overflow and that gives me the result I want just need to add in a scroll for the blue area)

Comment: @Crash1hd So are you through with my answer.

Comment: I totally appreciate your answers, and if javascript is the only way to make this work I am all for it.  Maybe I need to explain what I am trying to achieve see attached image

https://pasteboard.co/Jzw9Opn.png

Comment: It would then go up and disappear like the text does when you scroll and the next one below would show in its spot accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224306/discussion-between-crash1hd-and-scitrs).

Comment: @Crash1hd i edited the code again which would give same positioning to the red banner as shown in the attached image you could change the margin-left value as per your screen's resolution

Comment: Trying the new code gives me this
https://pasteboard.co/Jzwmwan.png

what I am trying to achieve is this
https://pasteboard.co/Jzwmf6N.png

Notice how the red is still in the same space as the blue but as you scroll it would go up with the blue in that space.